# Oracle 11g Internal error when logging in

Tags: oracle

I installed Oracle 11g in windows 7 but whenever I login using URL `https://localhost:1158/em/console/logon/logon`, with `username = sys` and `password = password`, I get an error saying

> "Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details."

I also searched intensively on Google but the solutions are not helping.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Did you check the log files?

Comment: From where can I access the log files?

Comment: @Anonymous useally from the server , however I am checking if it possible you get from windows folder

Comment: @Anonymous check if this answer helps for you to find the log file http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62540/oracle-enterprise-manager-where-do-i-find-the-error-logs